# Is it safe to stop dd after 30 mins, to add bs= to speed things up?

Tags: 16.04, dd, disk-image, cloning

I've been running dd for about 30 mins, and would like to stop using ctrl-c, and then restart using bs= to speed the process up.  Is this safe?  Will stopping dd midway through copying from internal ssd to external hdd break anything on either disk?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reastart the copy operation. There is no way to "resume" `dd` with different parameters.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...